# Server-side encryption Access denied AWS IAM user : Access denied when downloading files in s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have created an **AWS IAM user** to access an **S3** folder with this folder structure :

```
amazons3->fb-dev->au->csvfiles->may22->pincodes.csv
```

When i try to download the **pincodes.csv** file, the web broswer shows an **error**:

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
```

This is the json IAM policy i have attached to the IAM user :

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowUserToSeeBucketListInTheConsole",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowRootAndHomeListingOfCompanyBucket",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::fb-dev"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": [
                        "*"
                    ],
                    "s3:delimiter": [
                        "/"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowListingOfUserFolder",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::fb-dev"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": [
                        "*/${aws:username}/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowAllS3ActionsInUserFolder",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::fb-dev/*/${aws:username}/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**UPDATE**
AWS console shows this error :

```
Server-side encryption
Access denied
```

Do i need to pass access key and secret access key inside this json so that the IAM user can access the **pincodes.csv** file ?

Answer (score 0):

You're using a prefix of with `*/` as the first character.

For prefixes you should use absolute syntax for the prefix up until the last character (appending a `*`) at the end is fine.

This policy would only currently allow a path that started with this prefix `*/fb-dev`. In addition you appear to be referencing the S3 bucket name as `fb-dev` too (although I am not sure if thats the bucket name or not), check that you're using the correct name. I would expect it to look like the below syntax (where I have replaced bucket name).

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowUserToSeeBucketListInTheConsole",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowRootAndHomeListingOfCompanyBucket",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::$BUCKET_NAME"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": [
                        "*"
                    ],
                    "s3:delimiter": [
                        "/"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowListingOfUserFolder",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::$BUCKET_NAME"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": [
                        "${aws:username}/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowAllS3ActionsInUserFolder",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::$BUCKET_NAME/${aws:username}/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I am trying to give access to only **fb-dev** bucket. So, wouldn't **$BUCKET_NAME** give access to all buckets ?

Comment: I just replaced as I wasn't 100% sure it was the bucket, thats fine you switch it back. The biggest part is the prefix

Comment: **Server-side encryption
Access denied**. I can get inside the folders though

Comment: If the datas encrypted the user will need permissions to decrypt too, if this is KMS this will also need to be supported within the key policy